# How to detect SSL pinning on Android

Tags: android, ssl

I already have installed and configured `sslsplit` and generated the root certificate, and added it to the mobile phone (Android).

How to detect SSL pinning?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An app that uses SSL certificate pinning or public key pinning should fail to communicate with the server when you place a proxy in between the mobile device and the server it communicates with (because it would receive ssl split's certificate instead of the server's in the certificate chain).

If the app fails to communicate with the server - it means that  certificate pinning is working.

Comment: i know that Gmail application have **SSL** certificate pinning, but i still have connection to google mail servers and send/receive  letters via **sslsplit** proxy

Comment: Well in that case - you can debug an app (I suppose you want to test your own app). when implementing your SSL Factory - you should override the "checkServerTrusted" function and implement a check of the chain of certificates that the function receives. The certificate of your server should be the first one in the chain. if it's not - it means that there is a proxy between you and your server that is monitoring  the traffic.

Comment: No, i want to test different apps such as WhatsApp, Uber, Gmail and etc. on SSL pinning and HPKP. Also, i want to do this automatically.
Yes, i can reverse this apps.
I find SSL Factory in code, but i don't understand why i still have connected to servers via sslsplit proxy.

Comment: You'll need to use a tool to bypass certificate pinning instead of going into the code and doing it yourself. Take a look at https://github.com/ikust/hello-pinnedcerts to be able to run a certificate pinning test and verify your configuration is correct. After that you can take a look at https://github.com/iSECPartners/Android-SSL-TrustKiller which will help you by pass the pinning mechanism for a specific app. Look here for more info : https://isecpartners.github.io/android/2013/12/13/android-tools.html.