# How to detect SSL pinning is being done in the app?

Tags: android, ssl-security

I have already gone through this 
[How to detect SSL pinning on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34859658/how-to-detect-ssl-pinning-on-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you setup SSL interception with tools like mitmproxy or Burp and then import the proxy CA of this interception proxy into the android certificate store as trusted then you should be able to intercept the connection, i.e. get the plain text. If instead the application fails and maybe throws out some error about failing SSL verification than this application is probably doing SSL pinning.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance i will surely try this out. Meanwhile is there any content that i can read or learn from like a tutorial that shows how to test it ?

Comment: @gaurav4sarma: I'm pretty sure that there are several tutorials on how to to SSL interception, for example [this one](http://www.7xter.com/2015/07/intercepting-android-ssl-traffic.html). Once you get the experience to do such interception you will notice the cases when it fails because of pinning.